# Passing Information Between a Database through JSON

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, blackberry

I need to display information from an SQL database which resides on a server, to a remote webworks mobile device. I am extremely new to passing information from a server so bear with me. My normal understanding is that I would have an HTML file that accesses a php script which then itself connects to the database and displays the information.

However, in webworks the HTML/Javascript files reside on the device and are separated from any php file so I need a method to communicate to get the data from the database. I have looked through **JSON** and read all the tutorials on w3schools and I understand the syntax but I don't understand how to use it. How could it connect to a database? My aim is to simply display the table entries on a mobile device app running HTML5 webworks. Again I am very new to this so any explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, you should get a book. This is not something that can be explained in detail in a short answer on this site.

in summary however, you can either

1) send requests to your php script by submitting a form on an html page, which will load a new page filled with whatever PHP sends back. in this case you do not need to use JSON at all as PHP would be returning a full html page.

2) you can use AJAX. AJAX is a javascript method of sending requests to the server (PHP), and getting a response without ever loading a new page. you would use AJAX to send a request to the php page, the php page would access the database and send back a response, the javascript would then take the response and do whatever it needs with it. the response data is usually formatted in a JSON format, because PHP can easily create JSON, and javascript can easily decode JSON once it receives it as a response. to make using AJAX simpler, you may want to look in to using jQuery, a javascript library which can simplify the process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! At the current moment I like option 1. So where the forms are on an HTML page, how would this line look like : **<form action="insert.php" method="post">** assuming that insert.php is what retrieves the data when both the HTML and PHP files are together on the server side by side? Because on the device insert.php doesn't exist.

Comment: @user1152440 if the html page is not located in the same location as your php script on the server, then you will want to put a full path in your form's action, like action="http://www.somedomain.com/insert.php".

Comment: but if it is on a server, would you not need some sort of authentication like what php does in $con=mysql_connect("server","user","pass"); ? But since javascript is trying to connect, how would that happen?

Comment: @user1152440 I thought you weren't going to use javascript? Your client only sends a request to the server (php). PHP handles db authentication, grabbing info from the db, formatting the data however, then outputting it back to the client.

Comment: and this would work if the .php file is NOT on the server, but on a mobile device?

Comment: @user1152440 the PHP script has to be on the server in order to access anything from the database unless your mobile device has a php interpreter and relational database management software installed on it.

Comment: @user1152440 you really need to take some classes or get some books about internet programming, because with such a light grasp on these concepts, whatever you build is likely going to have problems security-wise or other.

Comment: So in essence I would have a html file which connects to a php file, then the php file displays the information by itself? or does it send it back somehow to the html portion? An example would be if I click on the html user interface "show data", the html will call the php script on the server and the next screen on my app will be the php doing the work?

Comment: @user1152440 you can think of PHP as just another html page that you can request from a server, except it's content can be dynamically generated using code, as opposed to being static text that is the same each time the file is requested by a browser. you might also consider just having the html file be located on your server as well. why keep them on the mobile device at all if it's just html?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think that's how the platform works, i.e. blackberry webworks. It uses HTML5, CSS, and Javascript to create an app. If I have some HTML, CSS and Javascript files making up my application they will need to talk to the server database and get the data somehow. And I don't know if showing the php result would work because then the app would function just as any website browser.

Comment: @user1152440 perhaps you should view the webworks documentation. I'm sure it is a very prominent piece of functionality, that is explained in thorough detail, since almost all mobile apps talk to servers.